# How do I know the variable ordering for CheckSatisfied?

Tags: python-3.x, drake

I am trying to write some unit tests for my constraints using the `CheckSatisfied` function.  How do I know the variable order of the input vector `x`?

E.g.

```
q = prog.NewContinuousVariables(1, 'q')
r = prog.NewContinuousVariables(2, 'r')
formula = le(q, r[0] + r[1])
constraint = prog.AddConstraint(formula)
assert(constraint.evaluator().CheckSatisfied([0.3, 0.5, 1]))
```

How do I know the which variable `0.3`, `0.5`, `1` corresponds to?

Is it dependent on how the constraints are added, and if so, how do I know the variable order for constraints added in the myriad of ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the variables is stored in the return argument of `AddConstraint`. If you check `constraint.variables()`, you would see the variable order. The pseudo code is

```py
constraint = prog.AddConstraint(formula)
print(f"{constraint.variables()}")
```